# Как сделать защиту для HTTPS запросов?

Tags: c++, qt, http, https

Мы делаем программу клиент, и встала такая задача как обмен HTTPS запросами между сервером(Сервер тоже написан на Qt) и клиентом. Всё вроде бы хорошо, но как сделать защиту для того, чтобы пользователь не прослушал соединение сниффером, и не мог самостоятельно(не используя клиент) получать и отправлять запросы для использования их в своих целях.

Comment: Пользователь может просмотреть все передаваемые данные еще в памяти приложения. Если хотите защититься только от подмены сертификатов, то зашивайте сертификат в само приложение.